# How can I keep the server from overloading?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a while loop in php:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

$search=mysql_query("SELECT * from chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search);
$type=$row['type'];
$id=$row['id'];
while($type!='n'){
  usleep(10000);
  $search=mysql_query("SELECT * from chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search);
  $type=$row['type'];
}

$run=mysql_query("UPDATE chat SET type='o' WHERE id=$id");

mysql_close($conn);
echo $row['message'] . "<br/>";

?>
```

It always runs to see if there are new entries in the database, but I dont know what to do to keep the server from overloading.  I tried usleep but I don't think it's enough.

Also I am getting this error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" and I know I can change the number of repetitions in the .ini file but would that be wise? Will it have a really bad effect on the servers performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `while` loop never terminates since you always get the last record, but make no changes to it.. so you go in the loop once and always check the same record without ever leaving the loop...

You should try to convert your infinite loop to a scheduled event that runs at some interval .. using cron jobs ..

---

***Update***

If you are *waiting* for some other action to change the type of the last record so that this code will catch it and exit the loop, then your algorithm is not fit for client/server applications..

You should predict at some other point the time where the record is ready to be altered and call the code at that time, instead of going to an infinite loop until some external event makes the loop non-infinite..

Comment: it does leave the loop because the UPDATE gets through and does its job, im just asking if there is something i can do for the server.

Comment: The UPDATE doesn't "get through" until after the loop terminates - which, as @Gaby said, is never.

Comment: dude, IT DOES! the rows are updated what dont you get? it works!

Comment: @Petre, it might get through only the first time by skipping the entire loop if the $type == 'n' .. if not it will enter the loop and never leave.. if not please explain the algorithm and also make sure the code you posted here is the same as the one you run ... check for matching `{}`.. unless you are expecting another event to happen from another page that will make this code leave the loop..

Comment: well it checks the first time and gets the value of $type and if there are no new entries it will be "o| from old, so "while" $type not equal "n" it checks the server and gives $type the new value, and it does this until it is "n" and then it updates the table and echos the entry.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

```
usleep(10000);
set_time_limit(11000);
```

**First answer**

What are you trying to achieve with this code? The timeout message comes from the script `usleep(10000)`.

Your code cannot detect immediate user input, your PHP code will run between user interactions with the server.

If you want to create a chat utility:

- Send your messages via AJAX each time an user hits `Enter` or `Send`
- Store the message received, along with the timestamp of the message received
- Select an `update time`, say 3 seconds
- Update the chat via AJAX, each `update time`
- Return the message that are `update time` old, or newer

Comment: it allways runs. on success, when the message was brought back, i call it again so it starts over and the response is very quick. im just asking if there is something i can do for the server.